# using regex or beautiful soup to grab someones website from instagram

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, instagram

I want to grab someones website from their instagram bio. Instagram hides this website in text/javascript tag so I can't grab the url like I would normally with an anchor from beautifulsoup. Here is a fragment of the page source that contains what I'm trying to capture:

> ...,"country_block":false,"external_url":"https://www.brittanyannecohen.com/pattern-control","blocked_by_viewer":false,...

I noticed that the link I want to grab is always attached to an `external_url` attribute in a dictionary (see picture below).

I attampted to grab this url through using regex but it's not working , see code below

```
url=re.findall("[\"external_url\":]['https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+']",soup)
```

but I get error :

> bad character range [-\w at position 31

Answer (score 1):

You have a square bracket where you should have a parenthesis:

```
url=re.findall("[\"external_url\":]['https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+']",soup)
url=re.findall("[\"external_url\":]('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+']",soup)
                                   ^--- change [ to (
```

The clue was in the error message `bad character range [-\w`, which meant the character class had started earlier that that expression. Looking earlier we find `['https?:...`, which doesn't makes sense either and that's
where the problem was.

I don't know if your regex actually works - it's too complicated to check, especially when there's a simpler way to do it.

Use this regex

```
(?<="external_url":")[^"]+
```

And the entire match will be your target url.

See [live regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/X2sXlvq045).

Comment: hum ok, it still doesn't get me what I want though, as in the regex doesn't work to find the url

Comment: @Bob see update to my answer with a simpler approach that is tested and works.

Comment: wait your using javascript? I'm using python

Comment: @Bob oops - python it is, in which case it's even *simpler* - see update to my answer

Comment: hum I don't understand why this won't work in my code. I see your demo but it's saying there are syntax errors when ran on my text editor.

Comment: @Bob you said you were using python. Your "text editer" may not support look behinds, but python does.

Comment: wait how is that a thing? Even if I'm running with python? It's saying theres a syntax error at the end of the url

Comment: so I just checked and I have definitely used look behinds before with this text editor so I'm not sure why your example isn't working

Comment: ok so i figured out the correct answer, would you like me to edit your post so that I can give you a check? the correct answer is url=re.findall("(?<=\"external_url\":\")[^\"]+",str(soup))